# Is there a module that creates a taxonomy of the world's languages?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Before I go creating my own taxonomy with the worlds languages as terms, I just wanted to see if there was a module out there that is already handling this?

EDIT:

I did lots of searching for a module before posting here but just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything before going my own way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched for such a module fairly extensively but was unable to find anything.

In the end, I used the [Taxonomy CSV Import/export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module, which allows you to create a list based on a CSV (comma-separated value) file, which is very easy to prepare.  I then referenced one of the [lists of languages on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_languages).  I would share my list with you except that mine is specific to my site; it doesn't list all human languages, but instead just the most popular ones in Asia.

Comment: Yeah that's the direction I was leaning. I did lots of searching for a module before posting here but just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything before going my own way. Maybe I'll release something on d.o for others to use then. Thanks for your help.